# SQL Server key holds list of keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have following code:

```
CREATE TABLE SONGS 
( 
       ...
       ISWC VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE SESSIONS 
(
       ... 
       RECORDED_SONGS VARCHAR(15),
       FOREIGN KEY (RECORDED_SONGS) REFERENCES SONGS(ISWC)
);
```

In `RECORDED_SONGS` I want to keep `ISWCs` of many songs recorded during session, separated with commas. Now I can store there only one `ISWC`. I can't change type of `RECORDED_SONGS` because then there will be problem with different types. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not store lists of songs in a delimited list. This is bad, bad, bad, bad:

- SQL has poor string handling functions.
- You cannot declare foreign key relationships.
- You cannot validate the values going into the string.
- SQL has much better ways of storing lists.

The correct way to store this is using a junction table, with one row per song in each session:

```
CREATE TABLE SESSIONSONGS (
   SESSIONID . . .,.
   ISWC VARCHAR(15),
   FOREIGN KEY (ISWC) REFERENCES SONGS(ISWC),
   FOREIGNKEY (SESSIONID) REFERENCES SESSIONS(SESSIONID)
)
```

Comment: The original design violates core relational database design principals 1) store only atomic data and 2) no repeating groups.